# Scraping a Twitter Image Object URL In R

Tags: r, web-scraping, twitter, rvest

I'm attempting to scrape images on twitter media urls (i.e. https://pbs.twimg.com/media/some-string-of-numbers-and-letters.jpg) using rvest but I continue to get empty html documents. There is an html hierarchy, but there's nothing in the elements. So for example:

```
library(rvest)
library(imager)

media <- read_html('https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DnLh3aJV4AANzdJ.jpg')
#Scrape the media url for the image
twt_img <- media %>% 
  html_nodes('img') %>% 
  html_attr('src')
twt_img
plot(load.image(twt_img))
```

However, when I run this code I get an html structure back with `View(media)` but it seems there are no elements that aren't character(0) or NA outputs. Does anyone know how to fix this or why this might be?

I can run the tutorial for image scraping found here: https://stat4701.github.io/edav/2015/04/02/rvest_tutorial/ but for some reason on Twitter, the html is interpreting strangely for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are accessing to a jpg file from the beginning in your code. You want to read the web page where that picture exists. In that tutorial, they identified an URL like one you have in your `read_html()`. Once you have a path for an image, you can try to download the image with `download.file()` for example.

Comment: @jazzurro, thanks! This actually helped me a lot. Just so I can flesh out what I had to do in order to save this particular image, all I needed was: download.file('https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DnLh3aJV4AANzdJ.jpg', 'filename.jpg') and that saved the jpg file to the current working directory as 'filename.jpg'.

Comment: I am glad that you found the solution.